# Running a timer in cpp,parallel to a program under execution

Tags: c++, opencv, timer

I'm running an OpenCV application on visual studio on a windows 7 machine. As part of the end application, I need a timer running in parallel to the OpenCV application which is under execution. The OpenCV application has real time video capture as input to a eye blink detection algorithm. The OpenCV code must be running continuously and can not be paused or stopped. However, to find the interval between blinks, I need to have a timer running after each blink. So the timer has to run while blinks are detected. I have gone through the SetTimer and CreateTimerQueueTimer functions and was unable to obtain a clear understanding of how to go about this. Is there any other way of running a timer in a c++ program? Any suggestions and solutions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a timer to calculate the interval between the blinks? Can't you just store the current time at each blink and subtract it from the previous?

Comment: Say I start the timer after the 1st blink,I'd like to make a decision based on whether the next blink occurs before the timer runs out or not.If the next blink happens after the timer has run out then I'd need to restart the blink count and reset the timer.Not sure if this made my problem clearer to understand.

Answer (score 0):

With `c++11` you can use `std::chrono` to make a simple timer:

```
  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  // do processing here
  auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << "time was " << 
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();
```

Edit in response to the comment on the other answer, you could do the following:

```
...
auto take = (end - start);

if(take > std::chrono::nanoseconds(x)) {
  // ... do whatever you want here
}
```

Oh and one thing to mention is that you can replace the `nanoseconds` with any other time unit.

Comment: thanks.I will look into this.I'm still trying to understand the complexity of my own problem.